# Calculate ISBN-13 check digit

Tags: code-golf, checksum

Write a function which, given the first 12 digits of an [ISBN-13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number#ISBN-13_check_digit_calculation) code, will calculate the entire ISBN via calculating and appending an appropriate check digit.

Your function's input is a string containing the first 12 digits of the ISBN. Its output is a string containing all 13 digits.

### Formal specification

Write a function which, when given a string *s* consisting entirely of exactly 12 decimal digits (and no other characters), returns a string *t* with the following properties:

- *t* consists of exactly 13 decimal digits (and no other characters);
- *s* is a prefix of *t*;
- the sum of all digits in odd positions in *t* (i.e. the first, third, fifth, etc.), plus three times the sum of all digits in even positions in *t* (i.e. the second, fourth, sixth, etc), is a multiple of 10.

### Example / test case

**Input**
`978030640615`

**Output**
`9780306406157`

### Victory condition

As a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, the shortest answer wins.

Comment: Are input and output supposed to contain dashes or only the digits?

Comment: Updated the description, the input and output are only the digits

Comment: Is outputting the full ISBN-13 acceptable as well?

Comment: Note that questions should really be self contained, so it would be helpful to include a description of the algorithm here.

Comment: For me above post is poor of example test... There would be at last 10 isbn and one of that has to return 0 as last digit...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Golfscript - 25 chars

```
{...+(;2%+{+}*3-~10%`+}:f
```

Whole program version is only 19 chars

```
...+(;2%+{+}*3-~10%
```

Check back here for analysis later. Meanwhile check out my old uninspired answer

**Golfscript - 32 chars**

Similar to the luhn number calculation

```
{.{2+}%.(;2%{.+}%+{+}*~)10%`+}:f
```

Analysis for 978030640615

```
{...}:f this is how you define the function in golfscript
.       store an extra copy of the input string
        '978030640615' '978030640615'
{2+}%   add 2 to each ascii digit, so '0'=>50, I can get away with this instead
        of {15&}% because we are doing mod 10 math on it later
        '978030640615' [59 57 58 50 53 50 56 54 50 56 51 55]
.       duplicate that list
        '978030640615' [59 57 58 50 53 50 56 54 50 56 51 55] [59 57 58 50 53 50 56 54 50 56 51 55]
(;      trim the first element off
        '978030640615' [59 57 58 50 53 50 56 54 50 56 51 55] [57 58 50 53 50 56 54 50 56 51 55]
2%      select every second element
        '978030640615' [59 57 58 50 53 50 56 54 50 56 51 55] [57 50 50 54 56 55]
{.+}%   double each element by adding to itself
        '978030640615' [59 57 58 50 53 50 56 54 50 56 51 55] [114 100 100 108 112 110]
+       join the two lists together
        '978030640615' [59 57 58 50 53 50 56 54 50 56 51 55 114 100 100 108 112 110]
{+}*    add up the items in the list
        '978030640615' 1293
~       bitwise not
        '978030640615' -1294
)       add one
        '978030640615' -1293            
10%     mod 10
        '978030640615' 7
`       convert to str
        '978030640615' '7'
+       join the strings
        '9780306406157'
```

Comment: After running the code through an interpreter, I think you can save some characters (in your 32 character Luhn-based solution) by getting rid of the first `{` and the last three characters; `}:f`.  I wonder if the same thing can be done for the first solution...

Comment: @MikeDtrick, those characters are how GS defines a function. The 19 char version does what you suggest, but the question asked for a "function"

Comment: You don't need the `:f` (yeah, I know functions were commonly named back then).

Answer (score 10):

### Python - 44 chars

```
f=lambda s:s+`-sum(map(int,s+s[1::2]*2))%10`
```

Python - 53 chars

```
def f(s):d=map(int,s);return s+`-sum(d+d[1::2]*2)%10`
```

Comment: I think f('9780306406159') outputs '97803064061598' instead of '9780306406157'

Comment: @Eelvex, the input string should always be 12 digits

Comment: Ah, somehow '9' sneaked in. Sorry...

Comment: I would like to leave a useless note that `f=lambda s:s+\`sum(map(int,s*7+s[::2]*2))%10\`` also has 44 chars

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell - 54 characters

```
i s=s++show(sum[-read[c]*m|c<-s|m<-cycle[1,3]]`mod`10)
```

This requires support for [parallel list comprehensions](http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/users_guide/hugs-ghc.html#ZIP-COMPREHENSION), which is supported by GHC (with the `-XParallelListComp` flag) and Hugs (with the `-98` flag).

Comment: Do you not need to include that flag in the count? Besides that, you can replace `[1,3]` by `[9,7]` and remove the `-` which saves you a byte :)

Answer (score 7):

### APL (27 characters)

```
F←{⍵,⍕10|10-(12⍴1 3)+.×⍎¨⍵}
```

I'm using Dyalog APL as my interpreter. Here's a quick explanation, mostly from right to left (within the function definition, `F←{ ... }`):

- `⍎¨⍵`: Execute/evaluate (`⍎`) each (`¨`) character given in the right argument (`⍵`).
- `(12⍴1 3)`: Reshape (`⍴`) the vector `1 3` into a `12`-element vector (repeating to fill the gaps).
- `+.×`: Take the dot product (`+.×`) of its left argument (`(12⍴1 3)`) and its right argument (`⍎¨⍵`).
- `10-`: Subtract from 10.
- `10|`: Find the remainder after division by `10`.
- `⍕`: Format the number (i.e., give a character representation).
- `⍵,`: Append (`,`) our calculated digit to the right argument.

Answer (score 6):

### PHP - <s>86</s> <s>85</s> 82 chars

```
function c($i){for($a=$s=0;$a<12;)$s+=$i[$a]*($a++%2?3:1);return$i.(10-$s%10)%10;}
```

Re-format and explanation:

```
function c($i){                     // function c, $i is the input

    for($a=$s=0;$a<12;)             // for loop x12 - both $a and $s equal 0
                                    // notice there is no incrementation and
                                    // no curly braces as there is just one
                                    // command to loop through

        $s+=$i[$a]*($a++%2?3:1);    // $s (sum) is being incremented by
                                    // $ath character of $i (auto-casted to
                                    // int) multiplied by 3 or 1, depending
                                    // wheter $a is even or not (%2 results
                                    // either 1 or 0, but 0 == FALSE)
                                    // $a is incremented here, using the
                                    // post-incrementation - which means that
                                    // it is incremented, but AFTER the value
                                    // is returned

    return$i.(10-$s%10)%10;         // returns $i with the check digit
                                    // attached - first it is %'d by 10,
                                    // then the result is subtracted from
                                    // 10 and finally %'d by 10 again (which
                                    // effectively just replaces 10 with 0)
                                    // % has higher priority than -, so there
                                    // are no parentheses around $s%10
}
```

Comment: Exactly the approach I took in my C# answer. Seems PHP is ~9 characters more efficient!

Comment: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##Jc6xDoIwFIXh3afocDWtiGlpS8FCnDQOJrIbYwgBYSlNgcn46lbU4QzfcvLb1vpsb1uLoMl9M5lq7HqDoSTPpndYQ5exSMMQ5FBeobutcRBAt2L7HSdEu3qcnIFyixkNYVgySubpl9eortp@/sQISvcwiGxQcSruh8tZ@1QllNNY0JjJxQwWM6Ukjf5IhKQq5fEPUkgWScHfvf12DT48fgA) with some tweaks

Answer (score 6):

### Windows PowerShell, 57

```
filter i{$_+(990-($_-replace'(.)(.)','+$1+3*$2'|iex))%10}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <s>78</s> <s>71</s> 66 characters

```
i s=s++(show$mod(2-sum(zipWith(*)(cycle[1,3])(map fromEnum s)))10)
```

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby - <s>73</s> 65 chars

```
f=->s{s+((2-(s+s.gsub(/.(.)/,'\1')*2).bytes.inject(:+))%10).to_s}
```

Comment: `"\\1"` -> `'\1'`?

Comment: @Nemo, thanks, my ruby is a bit rusty

Comment: Use Ruby 1.9 syntax `f=->s{...}`. Save 6 chars. Also write `s<<(...).to_s`instead of adding 48 and use `Fixnum#chr`.

Answer (score 4):

**Python - <s>91</s>, 89**

```
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
 def c(i):return i+`(10-(sum(int(x)*3for x in i[1::2])+sum(int(x)for x in i[::2]))%10)%10`
```

Comment: Spaces are optional between the first argument and `for` (and `in` and the third) in a list comprehension so long as it can be split up by the parser (not using a variable name).  -2 chars there.

Answer (score 4):

**C# (94 characters)**

```
string I(string i){int s=0,j=0;for(;j<12;)s+=(i[j]-48)*(j++%2<1?1:3);return i+((10-s%10)%10);}
```

With linebreaks/whitespace for readability:

```
string I(string i) 
{ 
    int s = 0, j = 0;
    for (; j < 12; )
        s += (i[j] - 48) * (j++ % 2 < 1 ? 1 : 3); 
    return i + ((10 - s % 10) % 10); 
}
```

Tested on several ISBNs from books on my shelf, so I know it's working!

Answer (score 4):

### J - <strike>55</strike> <strike>45</strike> 38

```
f=:3 :'y,":10|10-10|+/(12$1 3)*"."0 y'
```

eg

```
f '978030640615'
9780306406157
```

old way:

```
f=:,":@(10(10&|@-)(10&|@+/@((12$1 3)*(i.12)&(".@{))))
```

Comment: `(i.12)(".@{)y` can be replaced with `"."0 y`

Answer (score 4):

### C# – <s>89</s> 77 characters

```cs
string I(string s){return s+(9992-s.Sum(x=>x-0)-2*s.Where((x,i)=>i%2>0).Sum(x=>x-0))%10;}
```

Formatted for readability:

```cs
string I(string s)
{
    return s +
            (9992
            - s.Sum(x => x - 0)
            - 2 * s.Where((x, i) => i%2 > 0).Sum(x => x - 0)
            ) % 10;
}
```

We do not multiply by one or three, we just add everything, plus we add all even-placed characters one more time, multiplied by two.

9992 is large enough so that the sum of all ASCII characters is less than that (so that we may mod by 10 and be sure the result is positive, no need to mod by 10 twice), and is not divisible by zero because we add up all those extra 2*12*48 (twelve ASCII digits, weighed by 1 and 3) == 1152, which allows us to spare one extra character (instead of twice subtracting 48, we subtract 0 just to convert from char to int, but instead of 990, we need to write 9992).

But then again, even though much less beautiful ;-), this old-school solution gets us to 80 characters (but this is almost C-compatible):

```cs
string T(string i){int s=2,j=0;for(;j<12;)s+=i[j]*(9-j++%2*2);return i+s%10;}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```perl6
{$_~:1[.comb «*»(9,7)]%10}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcNRCoJAEADQq8yHikrI7M7szE5UF4mQivZLMexLoi7UEfrzYlsP3v02D5LHBaoE@/ws@vfWHbvrNF5g/bTrt7aNNqfS4Ss/zgukuugbSNMMO9OIhMIoLoAEUi//RhGcobcgkZU9GLEohajq@ZB/)

Comment: So base 1 can be used as a substitute for sum? Interesting!

Comment: @JoKing It's actually a very old trick in the world of APL and J :)

Comment: Wrong result for 978186197371 it seems to be 8 not 9...

Comment: Excuse me I think I had pasted the wrong number

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby - 80 characters

```
def f s;s+(10-s.bytes.zip([1,3]*6).map{|j,k|(j-48)*k}.inject(:+)%10).to_s[0];end
```

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 53 chars

```
sub i{($_)=@_;s/(.)(.)/$s+=$1+$2*3/ger;$_.(10-$s)%10}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it modifies `$_` in the replacement and then uses that altered value as part of the return.

Comment: @Xcali: fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

### dc, 44 chars

```
[d0r[I~3*rI~rsn++lndZ0<x]dsxx+I%Ir-I%rI*+]sI
```

Invoke as `lIx`, e.g:

```
dc -e'[d0r[I~3*rI~rsn++lndZ0<x]dsxx+I%Ir-I%rI*+]sI' -e '978030640615lIxp'
```

Answer (score 3):

## Q, 36 chars

```
{x,-3!10-mod[;10]sum(12#1 3)*"I"$'x}
```

Answer (score 2):

**D - 97 characters**

```
auto f(string s){int n;foreach(i,c;s)n+=((i&1)*2+1)*(c-48);return s~cast(char)((10-n%10)%10+48);}
```

Formatted more legibly:

```
auto f(string s)
{
    int n;

    foreach(i, c; s)
        n += ((i & 1) * 2 + 1) * (c - 48);

    return s ~ cast(char)((10 - n % 10) % 10 + 48);
}
```

The verbosity of D's cast operator definitely makes it harder to write obsessively short code though.

Answer (score 2):

**Java - 161 Characters** :(

```
int b[]=new int[a.length];
int d=0,n=0,j=1;
for(char c:a.toCharArray())b[d++]=Integer.valueOf(c+"");
for(int i:b)n+=(j++%2==0)?(i*3):(i*1);
return a+(10-(n%10));
```

Comment: This answer does not satisfy the first requirement, since it is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function taking string as argument. Using [Bubbler's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174553/43319).

```apl
⊢,∘⍕10|⍎¨+.×9 7⍴⍨≢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HXIp1HHTMe9U41NKh51Nt3aIW23uHplgrmj3q3POpd8ahz0f@0R20TgDKP@qZ6@j/qaj603vhR20QgLzjIGUiGeHgG/09TULc0tzAwNjAzMTAzNFUHAA)

`≢` length of argument (12)

`9 7⍴⍨` cyclically reshape `[9,7]` to that length

`+.×` dot product of the following with that:

`⍎¨` `evaluate each character

`10|` mod-10 of that

`,∘⍕` prepend the following the the stringification of that:

`⊢` the unmodified argument

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
SιO`3*+θTα«
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@NxO/wRjLe1zO0LObTy0@v9/S3MLA2MDMxMDM0NTAA) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn2ly//gczv9E4y1tM/tCDm38dDq/zr/Lc0tDIwNzEwMzAxNucxMjc2NzIDY0tiCy9DSwMjS1MzCxNzEiMvS2MTM3NjUwtzcyAQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
S            # Convert the (implicit) input to a list of digits
             #  i.e. 978030640615 → [9,7,8,0,3,0,6,4,0,6,1,5]
 ι           # Uninterleave it
             #  → [[9,8,3,6,0,1],[7,0,0,4,6,5]]
  O          # Sum each inner list
             #  → [27,22]
   `         # Push them both separated to the stack
    3*       # Multiply the top one by 3
             #  → 66
      +      # Sum them together
             #  → 93
       θ     # Only leave the last digit
             #  → 3
        Tα   # Take the absolute difference of this digit with 10
             #  → 7
          «  # And append this digit to the (implicit) input
             #  → 9780306406157
             # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
⁽Tẇ∑N₀%J
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigb1U4bqH4oiRTuKCgCVKIiwiIiwiOTc4MDMwNjQwNjE1Il0=)

Port of Jelly

### Explained

```
⁽Tẇ∑N₀%J
⁽Tẇ       # Triple every second digit
   ∑N     # -sum of that
     ₀%   # modulo by 10
       J  # append that result to the original input
```

Answer (score 1):

## Q (44 chars)

```
f:{x,string 10-mod[;10]0+/sum@'2 cut"I"$/:x}
```

Comment: This is actually incorrect I think

Answer (score 1):

### Scala 84

```
def b(i:String)=i+(10-((i.sliding(2,2).map(_.toInt).map(k=>k/10+k%10*3).sum)%10)%10)
```

Testing:

```
val isbn="978030640615"
b(isbn)
```

Result:

```
"9780306406157"
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <strike>80</strike> 79 characters

The function modifies the string in place, but returns the original string pointer to satisfy the problem requirements.

```
s;char*f(char*p){for(s=2;*p;s+=7**p++)s+=9**p++;*p++=48+s%10;*p=0;return p-13;}
```

Some explanation: Instead of subtracting 48 (the ASCII value of the digit `0`) from each input character, the accumulator `s` is initialized so that it is modulo 10 equal to 48+3*48+48+3*48...+48+3*48 = 24*48 = 1152.  The step `10-sum` can be avoided by accumulating `s` by subtraction instead of addition.  However, the module operator `%` in C would not give a usable result if `s` was negative, so instead of using `s-=` the multipliers 3 and 1 are replaced by -3=7 modulo 10 and -1=9 modulo 10, respectively.

Test harness:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 12
int main()
{
     char b[N+2];
     fgets(b, N+1, stdin);
     puts(f(b));
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy <strike>75</strike>, 66 chars

```
i={int i;it+(10-it.inject(0){t,c->t+(i++&1?:3)*(c as int)}%10)%10}
```

use:

```
String z = "978030640615"
println i(z)

-> 9780306406157
```

Answer (score 1):

#### APL (25)

```
{⍵,⍕10-10|+/(⍎¨⍵)×12⍴1,3}
```

Comment: The algo has to end with 10| because else it could return 10 in place of 0

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>78</s> 76 bytes

```python
lambda n:n+`10-(sum(int(a)+3*int(b)for a,b in zip(n[::2],n[1::2]))%10or 10)`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7RCoIwFIav3VPsJraTCzYtrcGexAQnKQk6xc2Levnlkoi6Ov8HH@f/p4e7jybxrbr6Xg/1TWMjTVwJfqB2GWhnHNUQp/sQamjHGWtW487gZzdRU0iZlMwUIlyAneCrIDhU3jXWWVWgiJJLfuYpz448EyfC8A/nBNjXSf@cjTkBVCIUusNXhufGLr0LI94tEkXTvO7DLQ0M7BOU2kz/Ag)

Takes a string as an argument.

## Explanation:

Using python slice notation, converts a string into a list of character pairs. ("978030640615" -> [("9","7"), ("8", "0"), ("3", "0"), ("6", "4"), ("0", "6"), ("1", "5")] )

For that list of pairs, converts each item into an integer and returns a+3b.

Sums all the results.

Gets the sum modulo 10, OR 10 if the remainder is 0. (This prevents the final digit from being 10 instead of 0.)

Removes the remainder from 10 to get the check digit.

Converts the calculated check digit to a string via deprecated backtick expression.

Returns the original number plus the calculated check digit.

## Edit:

Saved 2 byes by removing spaces (thanks [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)!).

Comment: You can remove the spaces before `for` and `or`

Comment: Result to me that 978186197371 has last digit 8 and not 9... I get that number from the only link I print in my Apl solution

Comment: Excuse me I think I have pasted the wrong number...

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╣Γ♠☼ù≤m╒X₧
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b9e2060f97f36dd5589e&i=978030640615%0A653726372938%0A190295684742%0A934673587724%0A&a=1&m=2)

This is a complete program instead of a function, as stax does not implement functions.

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
q   print input without popping and without newline
E   explode into array of decimal digits
97E [9,7] (this will become the repetition counts)
:B  repeat elements; repetition counts wrap around to cover all input digits
|+  get sum of array with repeated digts
A%  modulus 10
P   print
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=q++%09print+input+without+popping+and+without+newline%0AE++%09explode+into+array+of+decimal+digits%0A97E%09[9,7]+%28this+will+become+the+repetition+counts%29%0A%3AB+%09repeat+elements%3B+repetition+counts+wrap+around+to+cover+all+input+digits%0A%7C%2B+%09get+sum+of+array+with+repeated+digts%0AA%25+%09modulus+10%0AP++%09print&i=978030640615%0A653726372938%0A190295684742%0A934673587724%0A&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, <s>55</s> <s>53</s> 52 bytes

*Inspired by [Joey's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/791/80745). I'm impressed with her regex.*

```powershell
"$args"+($args-replace'(.)(.)','+40-$1-3*$2'|iex)%10
```

### Powershell, 55 bytes, whithout regex

```powershell
param($s)$s[1,3,5,7,9,11*2+0..11]|%{$r+=58-$_};$s+$r%10
```

Explanation:

- the index range = (the even positions `1,3,5,7,9,11` repeated 2 times + all positions  `0..11`)
- `$r+=58-$_` makes a sum of supplements up to `10+[char]'0'`
- `$s+$r%10` outputs the result

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

param($s)$s[1,3,5,7,9,11*2+0..11]|%{$r+=58-$_};$s+$r%10

}

@(
    ,("978030640615" , "9780306406157")

) | % {
    $s,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f $s
    "$($result-eq$expected)"
    $s
    $result
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True
978030640615
9780306406157
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), chars 38, bytes 76

```
{⍵,10∣10-10∣+/w,2×w[v/⍨∼2∣v←⍳≢w←⍎¨⍕⍵]}
```

I had some other test for see better and get definition from Wikipedia, and examples in the page:
https://isbn-information.com/check-digit-for-the-13-digit-isbn.html  test:

```
  h←{⍵,10∣10-10∣+/w,2×w[v/⍨∼2∣v←⍳≢w←⍎¨⍕⍵]}
  h 978186197271
978186197271 2 
  h 978168197271
978168197271 8 
  h 978186197371      
978186197371 9 
  h 978186197375      
978186197375 7
```

the formula i use would be in one not APL language if w is the argument =>

```
f(w)==w,(10-(sum(digit(w),2*digitsEVENINDICES(w))mod 10))mod 10
```

comment:

```
{⍵,10∣10-10∣+/w,2×w[v/⍨∼2∣v←⍳≢w←⍎¨⍕⍵]}
                   v/⍨∼2∣v←⍳≢w←⍎¨⍕⍵] call w the array of digits of ⍵, return even index
               2×w[                  consider all the digit even of w and multipy for 2
             w,                      put above that array, the array w
           +/                        sum all
      10-10∣                          10 - (above sum)mod 10
    10∣                               above mod 10
 {⍵,                                 add as digit to the number of argument, and return all that
```

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 25 bytes

```
dn[A~9z^8+*rd0<M+]dsMxA%p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b2luYWBsYGZiYGZo@j8lL9qxzrIqzkJbqyjFwMZXOzal2LfCUbXg/38A)

I know there's already a dc answer here, but 25<44 so I guess I feel 19 bytes of okay about it. 
This uses the fact that `8+9^z` is equivalent to either `-3` or `-1` mod 10 depending on whether z is even or odd. So I use `A~` to break the number into digits on the stack, but as I build the stack I multiply each digit by `8+9^z` where z is the current stack size. Then I add them all as the *function* stack unrolls, and print the last digit.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 57 bytes

```
f=s=>s+(10-s.split``.reduce((a,b,i)=>a+b*(3-i%2*2),0)%10)
```

You can invoke it like this:

```
f("978030640615")
```

Effectively, it goes through each (digit, index) pair (`b`, `i`), and works out `i % 2` (is `i` odd?), multiplies it by 2, and subtracts it from 3. Take a look at this:

For odd numbers:

- `(i % 2)` is 1
- `((i % 2) * 2)` is 2
- `3 - ((i % 2) * 2)` is 1

For even numbers:

- `(i % 2)` is 0
- `((i % 2) * 2)` is 0
- `3 - ((i % 2) * 2)` is 3

And so we have now generated the correct multipliers. From there it is simple, just add the current accumulator value, initialised at 0, to the current character multiplied by this generated multiplier. JavaScript automatically casts string to numbers when you do this multiplication.

Calculating the last digit is done by taking the last digit (by computing the value modulo 10), and subtracting this from 10.

Comment: Fail `000000000000`

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 19 bytes

```
{x,$10!2+/x*12#9 7}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VctLCsJAEEXRrWgb0GjE@nV9dD9xIGQckKy9UwYdOHiDw@O@rtNzam28v@ehQ9jT5TafkQ6xs6WNx1MJc2BQAcVaHkUrG2ku2JMYQFHVxYSSwaLG1c1IPtxa/rVJdMUwMvxS/Y/by8m@rQ)

Uses the `9 7` instead of `1 3` trick from [@Bubbler's J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174553/43319), as well as `2+/x...` to convert ASCII digits to usable numbers (e.g. "0" is 48, so adding two makes it 50 which allows it to work given the mod by 10 later).

- `12#9 7` build a 12-length list of `9 7` repeated (i.e. `9 7 9 7 9 7 9 7 9 7 9 7`)
- `x*` multiply the underlying ASCII character values by this pattern
- `2+/` seed a sum with `2` to properly offset the input digits
- `10!` mod by 10
- `$` convert result to a string
- `x,` append it to the input and return

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 20 bytes

```
ĐąĐŁř⁺1∧2*⁺·1ᴇ%1ᴇ-~ǰ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIQjrUcmHG08OvNR4y7DRx3LjbSAjEPbDR9uaVcFEbp1xzf8/29pbmFgbGBmYmBmaAoA)

```
Đ                          implicit input; Đuplicate
 ą                         convert to ąrray of digits
  ĐŁ                       Đuplicate and get Łength
    ř⁺1∧                   řangify [1,2,...,n], increment, and AND with 1
        2*⁺                double and increment (yielding [1,3,1,3,...])
           ·               dot product
            1ᴇ%            modulo 10
               1ᴇ-~        10 - previous result
                   ǰ       ǰoin stack with no delimiters; implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB - 82 chars

```
function c(i)
[i num2str(mod(10-mod(sum(str2num(i(:)).*repmat([1;3],6,1)),10),10))]
```

Answer (score 0):

### R, 147 characters

```
f=function(v){s=as.numeric(strsplit(v,"")[[1]]);t=0;for(i in 1:12)if(i%%2==0)t=t+s[i]*3 else t=t+s[i];paste(v,(10-(t%%10))%%10,collapse="",sep="")}
```

Usage:

```
f("978030640615")
[1] "9780306406157"
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, 25

```
,[:":10|0(-+/)"."0*1 3$~#
```

```
   f =: ,[:":10|0(-+/)"."0*1 3$~#
   f '978030640615'
9780306406157
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript: <del>73</del> 71 chars**

```
function _(b){for(i=s=0;12>i;)s+=((i*2&2)+1)*b[i++];return b+(10-s%10)}
```

Usage:

```
_('978030640615') //"9780306406157"
```

Comment: Why not define `_` as an arrow function too? That saves quite a few characters :)

Answer (score 0):

**Clojure 264 -> 241 characters:**

```
(defn s [a b] (let [c (count a)] (if (= 0 c) b (s (rest a) (+ b (* (if (= 0 (m c 2)) 1 3) (first a)))))))
(defn m [a b] (let [f (mod a b)] (if (= f 10) 0 f)))
(defn c [a] (str a (m (- 10 (m (s (map #(read-string %) (map str a)) 0) 10)) 10)))
```

Usage

```
(c "978030640615")
```

Non minified:

```
(defn sum [collection total]
  (let [len (count collection)]
    (if (= 0 len)
         total
         (sum (rest collection)
           (+ total
            (* (if (= 0 (mod len 2)) 1 3)
             (first collection)))))))

(defn mods [a b]
  (let [f (mod a b)]
    (if (= f 10) 
      0
      f)))


(defn create [isbn] 
  (str isbn
       (mods (- 10 (mods (sum (map #(read-string %) (map str isbn)) 0) 10)) 10)))
```

Usage:

```
(create "978030640615")
```

New to Clojure so I have to believe that can be knocked down.

Answer (score 0):

## Tcl, 79

```
proc f c {lmap a\ b [split $c {}] {incr d [expr $a+3*$b]};list $c[expr -$d%10]}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 87 bytes

```
proc C s {lmap c [split $s ""] {incr t [expr [incr i]%2?$c:3*$c]}
list $s[expr -$t%10]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WcFZoVihOic3sUAhWSG6uCAns0RBpVhBSSlWoTozL7lIoUQhOrWioEghGszLjFU1sldJtjLWUkmOreXKySwGKYeo0FUpUTU0iK39X1BaUqwQ7axgaW5hYGxgZmJgZmga@x8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 64 bytes

```
proc C s {list $s[expr ([regsub -all (.)(.) $s {-\1-3*\2}])%10]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclLCoAgFAXQrdxBQQWG9m/cMtRBRUQgJD6FIFq7CWd2/G5itO7esYDwmos8MpLHYx0K6Y6Twga2GoOiLpOUeJkSrK1U8@kyF1x/0QZPkAvmceItHzo@iF7HHw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 16 bytes

```
S:(→sΣz¤*or;¢"97
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P9hK41HbpOJzi6sOLdHKL7I@tEjJ0vz///9A0sLA2MDMxMDM0FQJAA)

#### Explanation

Instead of subtracting the sum from 10 I use negated coefficients, the rest is pretty self-explanatory:

```
S:(              )  -- apply the following function and append result to itself:
   →s               -- mod 10 / last digit
     Σ              -- sum
      z      ¢"97   -- zip input with ['9','7','9','7'...] under:
       ¤ (r;)       --   convert both chars to number, then
        *           --   multiply
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 21 bytes

```
,10":@|1#."."+*9 7$~#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WuoKNQa6VgoADE/3UMDZSsHGoMlfWU9JS0tSwVzFXqlP9rcnGlJmfkK6QpqFuaWxgYG5iZGJgZmqr/BwA)

#### How it works

```
,10":@|1#."."+*9 7$~#
                    #  Take length of input
               9 7$~   Repeat 9 7 that many times
          "."+*        Multiply (elementwise) to the digits
       1#.             Sum
 10   |                Modulo 10
   ":@                 Format to string
,                      Append to the end of the input string
```

The negative of `a + 3b + c + 3d + ...` modulo 10 is equal to `9a + 7b + 9c + 7d + ...` modulo 10.

Answer (score 0):

## [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), 106 bytes

```
1 INPUT T$:FOR I=1 TO 12 STEP 2:O=O+VAL(MID$(T$,I,1)):E=E+3*VAL(MID$(T$,I+1,1)):NEXT:PRINT 10-(O+E) MOD 10
```

It ain't pretty, but it works.

```
? 978030640615
7
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>120</s> <s>108</s> <s>83</s> <s>77</s> 69 bytes

```
{s->s+(10-(s.map{it.toInt()-48}.chunked(2).sumBy{it[0]+3*it[1]})%10)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7BCoJAFEX3fsVDCOYlyphmJmjQLmjXMlwMOtWgjuKMQYjfPo31NvfCuXBe0@tWSPNmLTwmWWVAbnoU8ongF/CvkJtZ@YXySEh9ooKODbPQge4vUhP043QJqtckG16THQZq6s4fy@@09KKtzbBccBNSXIwVQMeEJAizA/ZWq@ZKQw4jZ/VVSG7ZKQPX/fHB6nUryfoZWYeIzmKOh5RGNIlpEu6/)

Thanks to @ovs for removing 8 bytes!!

Comment: I don't think you need `.absoluteValue` as all digits are non-negative, So [this](https://tio.run/##JY7BCoJAFEX3fsVDCOYlyphmJmjQLmjXMlwMOtWgjuKMQYjfPo31NvfCuXBe0@tWSPNmLTwmWWVAbnoU8ongF/CvkJtZ@YXySEh9ooKODbPQge4vUhP043QJqtckG16THQZq6s4fy@@09KKtzbBccBNSXIwVQMeEJAizA/ZWq@ZKQw4jZ/VVSG7ZKQPX/fHB6nUryfoZWYeIzmKOh5RGNIlpEu6/) works for 69 bytes.

Comment: you're right! thanks! I removed it after, to get it to 77 bytes, but your edit was much better

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 24 bytes

```
0{:9)68**-:nl2%2*7+*+a%!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/36DaylLTzEJLS9cqL8dI1UjLXFtLO1FV8f///7rFluYWBsYGZiYGZoamAA)

**Explanation**

```
0                      !  # initiates sum (final digit) as 0
 {                        # get the next digit
  :9)68**-                # convert from char to int for any iteration except the last
          :n              # print the digit
            l2%2*7+*      # multiply the digit by either 9 or 7 alternately
                    +     # add to sum
                     a%   # mod sum by 10
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 48 bytes

```perl
sub f{"@_"=~s/(.)(.)/$t-=$1+3*$2/ger;"@_".$t%10}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhrVrJIV7Jtq5YX0NPE4j0VUp0bVUMtY21VIz001OLrEHSeiolqoYGtf@LEysV0lTi/1uaWxgYG5iZGJgZmv7LLyjJzM8r/q/ra6pnYGjwXzcPAA)

Doing this as a full program would be shorter:

#### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 31 bytes

```perl
s/(.)(.)/$\-=$1+3*$2/ger;$\%=10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX0NPE4j0VWJ0bVUMtY21VIz001OLrFViVG0NDf7/tzS3MDA2MDMxMDM0/ZdfUJKZn1f8X9fXVM8AKKtbAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ȮD×Ðe3SN%⁵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///EOpfD0w9PSDUO9lN91Lj1/@H2//8tzS0MjA3MTAzMDE0B)

### How it works

```
ȮD×Ðe3SN%⁵ - Main link. Takes n on the left
Ȯ          - Print n
 D         - Convert to digits
   Ðe      - To even indices:
  ×  3     -   Triple
      S    - Take the sum
       N   - Negate
        %⁵ - Mod 10
             Implicitly print this digit
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 118 bytes

```go
func f(n int)int{o,e:=0,0
for i,x:=1,n;i<13;i++{if i%2==0{o+=x%10}else{e+=x%10}
x/=10}
return n*10+(10-(o+3*e)%10)%10}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZY5BasMwFET3OoUIBKRISb9qx3Gc6gztFUyQgkj8FRQ5GERO0o0p9BA9Sm9Tq_Wui2H4zPDnvX-c_Ph1bY_n9mRo1zokrrv6EDcL28XFZx_tuv6-2x6P1DKkDiOflLw0jQYJxPpAnRwarSQe3IsqDk6I5Cx1y2etIXmhh6WCh7ncTDLzQYYnnS2Y2AekuFIgmII186JYGT5Vsh7z-uvvemZjPBFs9H5XQwFVCZXakrcw8VyQocyAnBPMeaEqVdalgv_5_HYc__wH)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I/O as a string.

```
+¬xÈ*YgDìÃìÌnA
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=K6x4yCpZZ0Tsw%2bzMbkE&input=Ijk3ODAzMDY0MDYxNSI)

```
+¬xÈ*YgDìÃìÌnA     :Implicit input of string U
+                  :Append
 ¬                 :  Split U
  x                :  Reduce by addition
   È               :  After passing each element at index Y through the following function
    *              :    Multiply by
     Yg            :      Index Y into
       D           :        13
        ì          :        To digit array
         Ã         :  End reduction
          ì        :  To digit array
           Ì       :  Last element
            n      :  Subtract from
             A     :   Ten
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 17 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 13.99 bytes

```
DZLdZl.SAu3*+n10%
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYbXaJ8UqJy9IIdS421tPMMDVQh4lDpBWsszS0MjA3MTAzMDE0hYgA)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
DZLdZl.SAu3*+n10%  # Implicit input
DZL                # Print the input without a trailing newline
   dZl             # Convert it to a list of digits and uninterleave
      .SAu         # Sum each list and dump onto the stack
          3*+      # Multiply the top one by 3 and add together
             n10%  # Negate and mod by 10
                   # This is output implicitly, concatenated onto the input,
                   # which was output without a newline at the start
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
zʂẸ3×+ṄT%a
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpdS7IKlpSVpuhYbqk41Pdy1w_jwdO2HO1tCVBOXFCclF0MlF6yxNLcwMDYwMzEwMzSFiAEA)

##### Explanation

```python
zʂẸ3×+ṄT%a  # Implicit input   ->  978030640615
z           # Uninterleave     ->  [[9,8,3,6,0,1],[7,0,0,4,6,5]]
 ʂ          # Sum each         ->  [27,22]
  Ẹ         # Dump onto stack  ->  27, 22
   3×       # Triple           ->  27, 66
     +      # Add              ->  93
      Ṅ     # Negate           ->  -93
       T%   # Mod 10           ->  7
         a  # Append to input  ->  9780306406157
            # Implicit output
```

Answer (score -1):

### Python

```
>>>r=input()
>>>a=0
>>>for x in r[::2]:
    a+=int(x)
>>>for x in r[1::2]:
    a+=int(x)*3
>>>a=(10-(a%10))%10
print(r+str(a))
```

Comment: I've added the language name to your answer; I was going to add a character count too but it looks like you've cut and paste from the REPL. Could you change this so it's a function as requested in the question and add a character count?