# Validate a barcode

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

A barcode of EAN-13 [symbology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode#Symbologies) consists of 13 digits (0-9). The last digit of this barcode is its check digit. It is calculated by the following means (the barcode `8923642469559` is used as an example):

1. Starting from the second digit, sum up all alternating digits and multiply the sum by 3:

   ```
   8 9 2 3 6 4 2 4 6 9 5 5 9
     |   |   |   |   |   |
     9 + 3 + 4 + 4 + 9 + 5 = 34
                              |
                              34 × 3 = 102
   ```
2. Then, sum up all of the remaining digits, but do not include the last digit:

   ```
   8 9 2 3 6 4 2 4 6 9 5 5 9
   |   |   |   |   |   |
   8 + 2 + 6 + 2 + 6 + 5 = 29
   ```
3. Add the numbers obtained in steps 1 and 2 together:

   ```
   29 + 102 = 131
   ```
4. The number you should add to the result of step 3 to get to the next multiple of 10 (140 in this case) is the check digit.

If the check digit of the barcode matches the one calculated as explained earlier, the barcode is valid.

---

More examples:

`6537263729385` is valid.
`1902956847427` is valid.
`9346735877246` is invalid. The check digit should be 3, not 6.

---

Your goal is to write a program that will:

1. Receive a barcode as its input.
2. Check whether the barcode is valid
3. Return 1 (or equivalent) if the barcode is valid, 0 (or equivalent) otherwise.

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in terms of bytes wins.

Comment: why did the last digit (`9`) become a `4`

Comment: Sorry, will fix it :)

Comment: I recommend removing the 13-char check because it's trivial but annoying in certain languages. Up to you though whether you want to do input validation (_most_ people leave it out but you can leave it in)

Comment: OK, I will do that.

Comment: Can we take input as a list of digits? (sorry for all the questions)

Comment: What do you mean by list of digits? (Never mind the questions :))

Comment: (Assuming you didn't) I'd recommend posting challenges to [The Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) first in the future so these questions can be addressed before the challenge is posted to the main site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84783/discussion-between-hyperneutrino-and-wais-kamal).

Comment: [Quite related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/148181/is-my-barcode-valid), but for EAN-8 instead of EAN-13.

Comment: [Use this to generate valid barcode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/342/calculate-isbn-13-check-digit?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: You may want to edit your challenge description stating the input should be a number or string as you mentioned in the chat, since I see a few answers assuming they can input a list of digits (flexible I/O is usually the default).

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>45 40</s> 37 bytes

```ruby
->n{(n+n.scan(/.(.)/)*''*2).sum%10<1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWiNPO0@vODkxT0NfT0NPU19TS11dy0hTr7g0V9XQwMaw9n@BQlq0koWlkbGZiZGJmaWpqaVSLBdE0NjcyMLS0NLYxMjQSCn2PwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 55 bytes

```python
lambda s:not sum(int(i)*d for i,d in zip(s,[1,3]*7))%10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKi@/RKG4NFcjM69EI1NTK0UhLb9IIVMnRSEzT6Eqs0CjWCfaUMc4VstcU1PV0OB/QRFIYZqGkoWlkbGZiZGJmaWpqaWSpiYXVhkLoMx/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s> 10 bytes

```
εNÉ·>*}OTÖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3Fa/w52Htttp1fqHHJ72/7@FpZGxmYmRiZmlqaklAA)

**Explanation**

```
    ε     }      # apply to each digit
     NÉ          # is the current index odd?
       ·>        # double and increment(yielding 1 or 3)
         *       # multiply by the current number
           O     # sum all modified digits
            TÖ   # is evenly divisible by 10
```

Comment: Nice answer! Definitely shorter than what I was working on. I like the `x` you've used in combination with `O` to sum the entire stack in one go to combine the `*3` and `+` of the two numbers. As well as the `(T%` to get the remainder.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: The comparison feels a bit surperflous. Can you think of a counterexample to [εNÉ·>*}OTÖ](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3Fa/w52Htttp1fqHHJ72/7@FpZGxmYmRiZmlqaklAA) working?

Comment: Hmm, not really. It would be useful to have more test cases than the 4 we have now. Can't really think of anything where `S13S13∍*OTÖ` would fail right now (so well done golfing 4 bytes). It also seems similar as the Python answer (and Jelly as well I think; I can't really read Jelly all that well).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
D0;s2Sḅ3⁵ḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/FwLrYKPjhjlbjR41bH@7o/f//v4WlkbGZiZGJmaWpqSUA)

-4 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen (semi-port @Dennis)

Comment: `%⁵¬` can be `⁵ḍ`, or you could golf it to [10 bytes: `D0;s2Sḅ3⁵ḍ`.](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/FwLrYKPjhjlbjR41bH@7o/f//v4WlkbGZiZGJmaWpqSUA) with a semi-port of [_@Dennis♦_' answer here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148447/52210).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen oh cool, thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-!`, 14 bytes

```
¬Ë*(Ev ª3Ãx %A
```

---

```
¬Ë*(Ev ª3Ãx %A  Full prgram.
¬               Convert to array -_-
 Ë              Map
  *             Multiply current number by
   (Ev ª3Ã      1 if index is even, else 3
          x     sum
           %A   mod 10?
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=rMsqKEV2IKozw3ggJUE=&input=Ijg5MjM2NDI0Njk1NTkiIC0hCgo=)

Comment: It may be in the comments instead of question, but you aren't allowed to take the input as a list of digits: Question from _HyperNeutrino_: "_Can we take input as a list of digits? For example, instead of reading the barcode as "123", I'd read it as [1, 2, 3]_" Response from OP: "_No, it should be input as 123, string or number doesn't matter._"

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Sorry, I though it was allowed :c

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too until I saw the comments in the chat.. >.> I've asked OP to add it to the challenge description (or just allow an array of digits since I/O is usually flexible by default..)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>29</s> 26 bytes

```perl6
{:1[.comb «*»(1,3)]%%10}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2sowWi85PzdJ4dBqrUO7NQx1jDVjVVUNDWr/FydWKqRpqMRrKqTlF3GZmRqbG5kBsaWxhakOl6GlgZGlqZmFibmJkbkOl6WxiZm5samFubmRiZn1fwA)

-3 bytes if a list of digits is acceptable.

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                      }  # Anonymous Block
    .comb                 # Split into characters
          «*»(1,3)        # Multiply with 1 and 3 alternately
 :1[              ]       # Sum (conversion from base 1 is shorter than sum())
                   %%10   # Check if divisible by 10
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 34 bytes

```
Check[#~BarcodeImage~"EAN13";1,0]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/d85IzU5O1q5zimxKDk/JdUzNzE9tU7J1dHP0FjJ2lDHIFbtv76DQrWSmamxuZEZEFsaW5gq6SgoGVoaGFmamlmYmJsYmYMELI1NzMyNTS3MzY1MzJRqY/8DAA)

A port of my [EAN-8 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148208/74672).

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>69</s> <s>67</s> 62 bytes

```java
n->{int s=0,m=3;for(;n>0;n/=10)s+=n%10*(m^=2);return s%10<1;}
```

-5 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.
-1 byte thanks to [my own 1-year old answer for the *Is my barcode valid?* challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148269/52210), and *@OlivierGrégoire* to remind me of it.. xD

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY7BbsIwEETvfMVeKjltCYkd27GM@YKWC8eqSCYEFJqsUewgVSjfnpqWa4W0c9jZ2dE72Yudn/ZfU9Va7@HdNnidATQY6v5gqxrWtxVg51xbW4SKtA6PgImO9hgVxwcbmgrWgGBgwvnqGt/Bm@y1M0wfXE80rjKNC5NniX8x@JRnz6TbGprovg5Dj@Cjtcz1ON1qz8OujX332otr9tBFLrIJfYPHj0@wyR/U5tuHukvdENJzPIUWCaYVKRVloqCFUJyrt@QX9d@w4ExSEaVYyR@Fc5VRxUVZyILKR2HFCiEZL6WMKPfwOBunHw)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{               // Method with long parameter and boolean return-type
  int s=0,         //  Sum, starting at 0
      m=3;         //  Multiplier, starting at 3
  for(;n>0;        //  Loop as long as the input is not 0 yet
      n/=10)       //    After every iteration: integer-divide the input by 10
    s+=            //   Increase the sum by:
      n%10*        //    The last digit of the input multiplied by:
       (m^=2);     //    either 1 or 3 (alternating every iteration)
  return s%10<1;}  //  Then return whether the sum is divisible by 10
```

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##pY9NasMwEIX3OcUQCEhxLRzZsq26DvQAzSbL0oWiOK1SWzKSHAjBZ3fltttCITCzmL9v3juLi4jPx89JtsI5eBFK3xYASvvGnoRsYDeXAAdj2kZokCiMXt/A4Sr0x5AhnBdeSdiBhhomF29vYQlsnTyoOqlOxs5HIB8dtlGtomhF13QtI1nZxg9Wg11tkqdNNU4zsx8ObYD9Mi9GHaELqtDeW6Xfw2uBfyTtr843HTGDJ30Y@VYjTSRalpymeUaznDPGl0R@COsQJp3okYq3Ks5KTLx5tlZcEcbfPv6G5SwtaB6SpyW7F7bhCeUsL7Mio8W9MJ5meZGysiiC1f/BxsU4fQE) by taking the digits as an array of integers.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire [OP disallowed it I'm afraid](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47289922#47289922), although I've asked to reconsider the default flexible I/O rules. My 69-bytes version was the same as yours, except with added `.getBytes()`

Comment: Ok. The question itself wasn't clear on it. Anyways, here's a 62 bytes golf: [`n->{int s=0,i=3;for(;n>0;n/=10)s+=n%10*(i=4-i);return s%10<1;}`](https://tio.run/##hY7NbsIwEITvPMVeKjltkybxXyzXPEHLhWPVgwkBmYY1ih2kCuXZU9NyrZB2Djs7O/oO9mzzw/ZrbnsbArxbh5cFgMPYDTvbdrC6rgAb7/vOIrSk97gHzHSyp6Q0IdroWlgBgoEZ8@UlvUMw5bMzVO/8QDQuS40vpiqz8GTwoSofiTMsd5keujgOCCF5r5We5mvvadz0qfDWe/ZuC8cERtZxcLj/@ASb/VGtv0PsjoUfY3FKp9gjwaIljaqpYDUTinP1lv2y/hsWnMpaJCna8HvhSpW14qJhktXyXlhRJiTljZQJ5RaeFtP8Aw)

Comment: Also, indeed, the version was the same because I took your version, removed the `.getBytes()` and switch the input parameter just to show that different input meant shorter answer, before I saw that the chat showed that indeed that input method wasn't allowed.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Nice golf with `i=4-i`. And it indeed looked suspiciously the same including variable names. ;p

Comment: Actually, you could even take [your answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148269/16236) as idea for a golf and gain one more byte: `i^=2`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Lol, completely forgot about that answer. Funny how it's the exact same `m++%2*2*i+i` to `(m=4-m)*i` to `(m^=2)*i` (pretty obvious since the challenges are the same), hence the duplicated vote.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
.(.)
$&$1$1
.
$*
M`
1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqrEYAwDABQnzkCVxA9mm8zAYodikBgEBz7l4rn3nt993P2Ke2t55QXwBkLFsiAKxwNCvZeg9iExEI1wJSdbAiuCiU2CrUqLuQQLOas1X3sHw) Link includes test cases. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to Martin Ender's comment on @Leo's Retina answer to the EAN-8 question. Explanation:

```
.(.)
$&$1$1
```

Triplicate alternate digits.

```
.
$*
```

Convert each digit to unary.

```
M`
```

Count the number of character boundaries, which is one more than the number of characters.

```
1$
```

Check for divisibilty by 10, but allow for the 1 we just added.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 15 bytes

```apl
0=10|⊢+.×1 3⍴⍨≢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///38DW0KDmUdcibb3D0w0VjB/1bnnUu@JR56L/aY/aJjzq7XvUN9XT/1FX86H1xo/aJgJ5wUHOQDLEwzP4/6PeVdWPerdaqYcUlaaqP@puUXdLzClOVa89tCLt0AoNCwVLBSMFYwUzBRMgbQKkLRVMgdBSU8MMSBkrmAOFzaC0JZC2UDDV1DAEMg3AAqZASQugPnOwfnNNDZAakDHmQNoUKGUO1gkU0QQA)

Anonymous train, outputs 1 for True and 0 for False. TIO links to a prettified version of the output.

Totally not helped at all by @ngn or @dzaima (thanks guys).

#### How:

```apl
0=10|⊢+.×1 3⍴⍨≢ ⍝ Main fn
              ≢ ⍝ Tally the argument (will always be 13)
         1 3⍴⍨  ⍝ Reshape the vector (1 3) to 13 elements
     ⊢+.×       ⍝ Multiply the original vector by that, then sum
  10|           ⍝ Modulo 10
0=              ⍝ equals 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes

```python
lambda x,k=1,a=0:f(x/10,4-k,a+x*k)if x else a%10<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nctNCsIwEEDhq8xGaDRifmcyYm/iJmKDJbUW7SKePoYewcXbfPCW7/p4zaYm6OFap/i83SMUmXstY6/OqSsnraQ7ZhkPZZ/FmKDAMH0GiDutLvqfZXmP8wqpC2wsOuOQvWchm6C3ZLDFNvhNNCvDHoMjZ2gTtg7J@kDUTlF/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
!es*V*jT7l
```

Accepts input as a list of digits. Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21es%2AV%2AjT7l&input=%5B8%2C9%2C2%2C3%2C6%2C4%2C2%2C4%2C6%2C9%2C5%2C5%2C9%5D&debug=0), or verify all test cases at once [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21es%2AV%2AjT7l&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B6%2C5%2C3%2C7%2C2%2C6%2C3%2C7%2C2%2C9%2C3%2C8%2C5%5D%0A%5B1%2C9%2C0%2C2%2C9%2C5%2C6%2C8%2C4%2C7%2C4%2C2%2C7%5D%0A%5B9%2C3%2C4%2C6%2C7%2C3%2C5%2C8%2C7%2C7%2C2%2C4%2C6%5D&debug=0).

```
!es*V*jT7lQQ   Implicit: Q=eval(input())
               Trailing QQ implied
      jT7      10 in base 7 - yields [1,3]
     *   lQ    Repeat the above len(input) times
   *V      Q   Vectorised multiply the above with the input
  s            Take the sum
 e             % 10
!              Logical not
```

*Edit: saved a byte by replacing `,1 3` with `jT7`*

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 65 bytes

```r
function(b,y=b%/%10^(12:0)%%10)!sum(y[-1],y[(1:6)*2]*2)%%-10+y[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCsMgEEX3vUUXgqYJdUadcQI5idhFCkIXTaBtFp7emsWDz/u8TytLK8f2/L32Ta9jXVZ1V2AfGnC2RvVprt/jrWuaII81aZjJDJgH7OcE9lYT5FZ0FHTk0ZOEIOZSNAXHSB1xMZwCxKIEip498inEeWIXInPPTPsD)